# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10/24/2021, 02:49:28'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am currently trying to write an simple script which is adding one day to the current date.
But when running my script it errors out like this:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10/24/2021, 02:49:28'`

This is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7,
    a = int(a) + timedelta(str(nt))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10/24/2021, 02:49:28'
```

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

nt = '1'
a = datetime.now()
a = a.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
a = int(a) + timedelta(str(nt))
print(a)
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code? If so I would be very glad if someone could explain to me what I've made wrong and help me fix this problem.

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Ps: Feel free to question if something is unclear:)

Comment: you are trying to convert `10/24/2021, 02:49:28` into int

Comment: Your error is occuring because you are passing a string in to `int()` here: `a = int(a)`

Comment: @ViaTech so I don't have to convert a to int?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the integer value of a string, that's the way, yes, but it does need to actually be a valid integer.

```
print (int("22"))
```

> 22

And if turning the string into a number doesn't work, it gives that exception that you just saw.

```
try:
    int('Your string here')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Your string here'

You're doing weird things with the variable a. Calling a function is normal. But assigning the return value of that function to a wipes out the original datetime object. If you want to print out the time, then just print it.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a = datetime.now()
print ('printout of a timestamp:', a.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

> printout of a timestamp: 10/23/2021, 23:27:51

If you want a timedelta, use the parameters it provides. It's much clearer if you just use timedelta(days=1)

```
a += timedelta(days=1)
print ('one second later it is: ', a.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

> one second later it is:  10/24/2021, 23:27:51

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert datetime object to int object, which will raise error. If you want to add or subtract dates, then use the `timedelta()` method. Enter the seperation value between dates as `timedelta(days=1)` and add it or subtract it to the current datetime object. Your code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

a = datetime.now()
a = a + timedelta(days=1)
a = a.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")  #converted to string format

print(a)
```